# Session Data to Report Chart DataSource in Devexpress

Tags: session, devexpress

I want to use Session[CountryList"] for datasource reporting chart.

I added my chart to report however there is no code.

How can I add Session[CountryList"] as datasource and show it in my report chart?

Model:

```
public static IList<Country> GetCountries()
{
return new List<Country>(){
new Country("Russia", 50),
new Country("Canada", 231),
new Country("USA", 33),
new Country("China", 111),
new Country("Brazil", 14),
new Country("Australia", 140),
new Country("India", 434),
new Country("Turkey", 3),
new Country("England", 21),
new Country("Greece", 116)
};
}
}
public class Country
{
string name;
double area;
public string Name { get { return name; } }
public double Area { get { return area; } }
public Country(string name, double area)
{
this.name = name;
this.area = area;
}
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ReportViewerPartial()
{

Session["CountriesDatas"] = CountriesProvider.GetCountries(); //Country List

XtraReport1 report = new Q502351.Reports.XtraReport1();
report.DataSourceDemanded += report_DataSourceDemanded;
ViewData["Report"] = report;
return PartialView("ReportViewerPartial");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried on my side with your model data.

Below code will work on your side too.

```
public ActionResult ExportReportViewer()
{
XtraReport1 report = new CrmSoner.Reports.XtraReport1();
XRChart chart = report.FindControl("xrChart1", true) as XRChart;
List<Country> list = Session["CountriesDatas"] as List<Country>;
chart.DataSource = list;
chart.Series[0].ArgumentDataMember = "Name";
chart.Series[0].ValueDataMembers.Clear();
chart.Series[0].ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Area" });

return DevExpress.Web.Mvc.ReportViewerExtension.ExportTo(report);
}
```